# One dimensional heat equation using Fourier Transform for temperature distribution

Tags: heat-equation, fourier-transform

One dimensional heat equation is

$$ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} $$
and initial condition is

$$ u(x,t) = f(x) $$
I'm trying to find the temperature distribution by using Fourier transform for $ -\infty < x < \infty $

Comment: Have you tried doing a fouriertransform in x?

Comment: Googling "heat equation fourier transform" and first link gives a pdf with the desired result.